# Matching Word Regex

Tags: regex

Hello i want to match with regex this word

```
(Parc Installé)
```

from this text:

```
31/1/2017 17:19:23,4245986,ct0001@Intotel.int,Parc Installé,100.100.30.100
```

I did this regex  `',[A-Za-zA-zÀ-ú+ \/\w+0-9._%+-]+,'`
But the result is : `4245986 ans Parc Installé`.

How can i match only Parc Installé

Comment: Why not split with a comma and get the last but one item if at least 2 items exist? Do you really have to rely on context here?

Comment: Can you just do it by position in the string as @WiktorStribiżew suggests?  If not, we will need some more guidance about what should and should not match.

Comment: in other li logs i have a lot of Comma, i wanna match only the words between IP address and last Comma

Comment: Your regex contains such a fragment: `[A-Za-zA-zÀ-ú+ \/\w+0-9._%+-]`.
Note that you "repeat yourself" here.
I mean that `\w` (a word char, between `[` and `]`) stands for `A-Za-z0-9_`, so if you included `\w`, then don't include `A-Za-z0-9_`.
Another example is that you put `A-Z` 2 times. Why???
My advice: Keep your regexes tidy (e.g. without such repetitions), otherwise, when at some later time you will have something to change here
you will have **very serious** problems to figure out what
your initial intent was.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a regex based on a lookahead that will require a comma and digits/commas after it up to the end of string:

```
[^,]+(?=\s*,[\d.]+$)
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lw49YB/1)

**Details**:

- `[^,]+` - 1 or more chars other than `,`
- `(?=\s*,[\d.]+$)` -  a lookahead requiring

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `,` - a comma
  - `[\d.]+` -  1+ digits or dots up to...
  - `$` - ... the end of string

To make it a bit more restrictive, you may replace the lookahead with `(?=\s*,\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)` to require 4 sequences of dot-separated 1+ digits. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lw49YB/2).

If a lookahead is not supported (case with a RE2 engine), you might want to use a *capturing group* based solution:

```
([^,]+)\s*,[\d.]+$
```

Here, the part within `(...)` will be captured into Group 1 and will be accessible via a backreference or a function like `=REGEXEXTRACT` in Google Spreasheets that only retrieves the contents of a capturing group if the latter is present in the pattern.

Comment: Wiktor, I think this could be simplified this way : `[^,]+(?=,[^,]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/mHQAAR/2/

Comment: @stej4n: Possibly yes, but OP commented that it should be an IP address. So, I think the pattern should at least check for digits and dots. Otherwise, I do not see the point using a regex here (unless OP explains where the regex is used).